# Excel image comments --> picture objects

Tags: excel, vba, loops, comments

I get an excel report each week with images in the comments.
I am trying to loop through all comments in the file, and paste all the comments to the worksheet as pictures

I have tried the method found on the "Ku Tools" website...
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4328-excel-extract-image-from-comment.html

Here is the code from the website (that i use exactly)...

```
Sub CommentPictures()
'Updateby Extendoffcie 20161207
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim visBool As Boolean
    Dim cmtTxt As String
    Dim jpgPath As String
    Dim shpHeight As Integer, shpWidth As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        With cmt
            cmtTxt = .Text
            shpHeight = .Shape.Height
            shpWidth = .Shape.Width
            .Text Text:="" & Chr(10) & ""
            visBool = .Visible
            .Visible = True
            On Error Resume Next
            Set xRg = .Parent.Offset(0, 1)
            .Shape.CopyPicture _
              Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
            xRg.PasteSpecial
            Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            Selection.Width = xRg.Width
            Selection.Height = xRg.Height
            .Visible = visBool
            .Text Text:=cmtTxt
        End With
    Next cmt
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I use this code, it works sporadically

When it "doesn't work", the macro creates an **invisible** rectangle object

When it does work, it creates a visible **rectangle** image/object (rectangle shape that can be seen).

In the below screenshot, row 715 contains a visible image (when the macro works right) and row 755 contains an invisible image (when it doesn't work right)

[Visible vs Non-Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeWNl.png)

I want to make all 700+ image comments actual images as easily as possible, if anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

My hypothesis is that there might be a size limit, because the macro worked perfectly when I ran it in a small batch of a couple dozen images

Thanks

Comment: No chance in having the report changed so the images aren't in comments?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` seems like a great place to start. Personally, I'd comment out that line and step through until it throws the error. It looks like there is a problem setting the range for some reason. If it is set to `Null`, the `.PasteSpecial` will probably give you the empty frame you are seeing.

Comment: @Christopher D. 
setting the range seems to be the problem, but when I take out the error handler, it does not fix anything. It still pastes the empty image objects

Comment: I don't have any experience with comment objects, do you know what the offset is for?